# How can I insert content into a DOM document using EntityReferences?

Tags: java, html

I'm using org.w3c.dom.Document in Java and inserting EntityReference nodes. These are added OK but are stripped out by javax.xml.transform.Transformer. This code explains what I mean:

```
    DOMImplementation dmi = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance().getDOMImplementation("");
    Document doc = dmi.createDocument(null, "html", null);
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(doc.createTextNode("AT"));
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(doc.createEntityReference("amp"));
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(doc.createTextNode("T"));
    Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
    tr.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

The output of this is

```
<html>ATT</html>
```

and I want

```
<html>AT&amp;T</html>
```

I know that if I do `doc.createTextNode("AT&T")` directly it will escape the '&' for me, so I'm looking for a way to

- preserve my EntityReferences, or
- let me look up the defined Entities, or
- fill in the Entity's text as a child of the EntityReference.

I have to deal with the entity reference names because I have to implement an interface that looks like

```
interface Xxx {
 void addText(String text);
 void addEntity(String entName);
 ...
}
```